# What is "the dark simple curtain" in Ted Hughes' "Criminal Ballad"?

Tags: meaning, ted-hughes, crow

In the poem "[Criminal Ballad](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ShcIjIYxAMoC&pg=PT35)", Ted Hughes describes a chain of tragedies happening in parallel with a man's simple moments of life. One of these is the following:

> And when he ran and got his toy squealing with delight
>   An old man pulled from under the crush of metal
>   Gazed towards the nearby polished shoes
>   And slowly forgot the deaths in Homer
>   The sparrowfall natural economy
>   Of the dark simple curtain

I'm trying to understand how the images in the last two lines are related to each other. So, the "sparrowfall" image is easy:

> "'Sparrowfall' refers us to Matthew 10:29, where Christ is comforting
>   the disciples by telling them that God's providence [...] covers
>   everything, even the smallest details such as man himself would
>   forget. For Hughes, this is no comfort to the old man at his death."
>   — Craig Robinson (1989). [*Ted Hughes As Shepherd Of Being*, p. 61](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OXmuCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA61). Palgrave Macmillan.

Also, it might be helpful to note that Hamlet makes the same biblical reference, saying that "there is a special providence in the fall of a sparrow".

Then, when reading Matthew 10:29, we can also see that the "sparrowfall" is given in the context of commerce, and thus we can understand the meaning of "natural economy":

> Are not two sparrows sold for a farthing? and one of them shall not fall on the ground without your Father.
>   — *Matthew 10:29, King James Bible*

But what does a "dark simple curtain" have to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Dark simple curtain’ is a metaphor for death: a curtain shuts out the light, and comes down at the end of a performance. ‘Simple’ means ‘uncomplicated’ but also has an archaic sense of ‘medicine’, which could allude to the idea of death as a cure for all ills.

The difficult bit is ‘natural economy’. The post suggests that it alludes to the price of sparrows, but I don’t think this can be right, since ‘[natural economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_economy)’ is a type of economy in which there is no money or medium of exchange, and so goods must be bartered or shared. In a natural economy, you can’t sell two sparrows for a farthing, because there are no farthings; instead you must exchange them—but for what?

One way to make sense of this is to suppose that Hughes is gesturing towards the Christian doctrine of ‘[economy of salvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Salvation)’, the exchange of faith and works for eternal life.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the Economy of Salvation. Thanks!